# Фильтр для каждого столбца в QTableView

Tags: qt, qwidget

Имеется tableview, который отображает некоторую модель данных. В модели несколько столбцов (текст, числа, чекбоксы).

Так же есть прокси модель, которая фильтрует данные.

Необходимо, создать для каждого столбца виджет, в который мы будем вводить данные для фильтрации.

В идеале, хочется засунуть виджеты прямо в шапку tableview. Но для этого нужно написать свой QHeaderView и нагородить кучу кода, что не есть хорошо.

Думаю над вариантом: накидать на форму несколько lineedit в какой-то layout, чтоб это автоматически подстраивалось под qtableview по размерам и в итоге красиво отображалось. Чтобы каждый фильтр-виджет был именно над тем столбцом, для которого он предназначен.

Какие есть инструменты для решения такой задачи?
[image: пример отображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @magrif, Ваше решение вдохновило меня.

Я решил задачу таким способом. Идею реализации я описал выше в вопросе. Однако виджеты создаются программно (динамически).

**Заранее**, руками, на форму я добавил `layout`, в котором буду хранить виджеты. Это сверху, над `tableview`.

1. Подключаю модель к `tableview`

```
ui->view_scan->setModel(m_scanning_filter_model);
ui->view_scan->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeMode::Stretch);
```

2. Теперь мы знаем кол-во столбцов. Таким образом, для каждого столбца в `tableview` создаем свой виджет

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_scanning_model->columnCount(); i++) {
    ui->filter_layout->addWidget(create_filter_widget_by_scanning_column(i));
}
```

В методе `create_filter_widget_by_scanning_column` определяем по индексу столбца, какой виджет будет создан для этого столбца. Сразу же к созданному виджету подключаем необходимые слоты.

```
QWidget *MainWindow::create_filter_widget_by_scanning_column(const int &column) const
{
    switch (column) {
    // пример текстового поля
    case 0: {
        auto widget = new QLineEdit();
        widget->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[A-Za-z]{0,255}")));
        connect(widget, &QLineEdit::textChanged,
                m_scanning_filter_model, &ScanningFilterModel::set_type);
        return widget;
    }
        // пример чекбокса
    case 7: {
        auto widget = new QCheckBox();
        widget->setTristate(true);
        widget->setCheckState(Qt::CheckState::PartiallyChecked);
        connect(widget, &QCheckBox::stateChanged,
                m_scanning_filter_model, &ScanningFilterModel::set_enable);

        return widget;
    }
    default: return nullptr;
    }
}
```

3. Для красивого отображения виджетов (чтоб виджет был точно над столбцом, за который отвечает) подключаем изменение размера. Таким образом, при изменении размера окна или таблицы виджеты будут на своих местах.

```
connect(ui->view_scan->horizontalHeader(), &QHeaderView::sectionResized,
        this, [this] (int index, int old_size, int new_size)
{
    Q_UNUSED(old_size);
    auto widget = ui->filter_layout->itemAt(index)->widget();
    widget->setMaximumWidth(new_size - 5);
});
```

Вот то, что получилось в итоге:
[image: результат]

Answer (score 2):

Думаю в шапку виджет засунуть не получится, если верить [докам](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html):

> Note: Each header renders the data for each section itself, and does
>   not rely on a delegate. As a result, calling a header's
>   setItemDelegate() function will have no effect.

Как вариант - при клацанье на шапку нужной секции над ней появляется виджет с lineedit'ом, и при вводе текста в него вызывать член-функции сортировки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример кода картинки выше:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel;

  for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
      for (int column = 0; column < 4; ++column) {
          QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("row %0, column %1").arg(row).arg(column));
          model->setItem(row, column, item);
      }
  }
ui->tableView->setModel(model);

//При клацанье на заголовок секции открывать вижет сортировки
connect(ui->tableView->horizontalHeader(), &QHeaderView::sectionClicked, [this](int section) {
    QHeaderView* headerView = ui->tableView->horizontalHeader();
    QWidget* sortWidget = new QWidget(this, Qt::Popup);
    sortWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    sortWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 128);"
                              "color: white;");
    QHBoxLayout* lo = new QHBoxLayout(sortWidget);
    QLineEdit* le = new QLineEdit(sortWidget);
    connect(le, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [this](const QString& toSort) {
        //TODO вызываем логику сортировки
    });
    lo->addWidget(le);
    sortWidget->setLayout(lo);
    sortWidget->resize(headerView->sectionSize(section), 30);
    sortWidget->show();
    const auto sx = section * headerView->sectionSize(section) + (this->pos().x() + ui->tableView->pos().x());
    const auto sy = this->pos().y() + ui->tableView->pos().y();
    sortWidget->move(sx, sy);
});
```

Только лучше конечно всю эту красоту инкапсулировать в какой-нибудь `SortPopUpWidget`.